# trying to configure DailyRollingFileAppender for tomcat8 logging but not working

Tags: logging, log4j, tomcat8, rollingfileappender

I am trying to configure DailyRollingFileAppender for tomcat logging and for this I follow this guide https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html section "Using Log4j" now when I make change according to it and restart tomcat, it creates only 2 files in ${catalina.base}/logs/ directory with name "catalina.out" and "localhost_access_log.2017-06-21.txt". This is ok I think, but now the actual problem is I want to implement DailyRollingFileAppender which rollover flog file at every minute. So as I think the expected behaviour is make compression of catalina.out file and then clear the same file.
For this, log4j.properties file is as follow

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=app.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-mm
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

I had put log4j.properties file in ${catalina.base}/lib directory.

This configuration not even give expected behaviour. It even not create app.log file in ${catalina.base}/logs directory.

I also try to put size base RollingFielAppender, which even don't work

Please help me in this configuration for any of configuration time base or size base rolling.

Do I need to set any environment variable like "catalina.base"?

Comment: log4j version is 2.8.2

Comment: Please provide log4j 2 related configuration for tomcat internal logging

Comment: Please try to change the date pattern from `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-mm` to `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm`. I think Tomcat does not recognize the pattern.